# Add MySQL query results to R dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, sql, r, rmysql

I want to convert a MySQL query from a python script to an analogous query in R. The python uses a loop structure to search for specific values using genomic coordinates:

```
SQL = """SELECT value FROM %s FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites)
                        WHERE `chrom` = %d AND `site` = %d""" % (Table, Chr, Start)
cur.execute(SQL)
```

In R the chromosomes and sites are in a dataframe and for every row in the dataframe I would like to extract a single value and add it to a new column in the dataframe

So my current dataframe has a similar structure to the following:

```
df <- data.frame("Chr"=c(1,1,3,5,5), "Site"=c(100, 200, 400, 100, 300))
```

The amended dataframe should have an additional column with values from the database (at corresponding genomic coordinates. The structure should be similar to:

```
df <- data.frame("Chr"=c(1,1,3,5,5), "Site"=c(100, 200, 400, 100, 300), "Value"=c(1.5, 0, 5, 60, 100)
```

So far I connected to the database using:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user="root", password="",
                 dbname="MyDataBase")
```

Rather than loop over each row in my dataframe, I would like to use something that would add the corresponding value to a new column in the existing dataframe.

**Update with working solution based on answer below:**

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user="root", password="",
                 dbname="MyDataBase")

GetValue <- function(DataFrame, Table){
  queries <- sprintf("SELECT value as value 
                     FROM %s FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) 
                     WHERE chrom = %d AND site = %d UNION ALL SELECT 'NA' LIMIT 1", Table, DataFrame$Chr, DataFrame$start)
  res <- ldply(queries, function(query) { dbGetQuery(con, query)})
  DataFrame[, Table] <- res$value
  return(DataFrame)
}
df <- GetValue(df, "TableName")
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what the result is suppose to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this. First, build up your queries, then execute them, storing the results in a column of your dataframe. Not sure if the do.call(rbind part is necessary, but that basically takes a bunch of dataframe rows, and squishes them together by row into a dataframe.

```
queries=sprintf("SELECT value as value FROM %s FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) WHERE chrom = %d AND site = %d UNION ALL SELECT 0 LIMIT 1", "TableName", df$Chrom, df$Pos)
df$Value = do.call("rbind",sapply(queries, function(query) dbSendQuery(mydb, query)))$value
```

I played with your SQL a little, my concern with the original is with cases where it might return more than 1 row.

Comment: I was able to get it somewhat working by using: `queries <- sprintf("SELECT coalesce(value,0) as value FROM %s FORCE INDEX (chrs) FORCE INDEX (sites) WHERE chrom = %d AND site = %d LIMIT 1", "TableName", df$Chrom, df$Pos)` and then `dbGetQuery(con, queries)`. However, this only gives the first result. If I do the second part of your code `df$Value <- do.call("rbind",dbGetQuery(con, queries))$value` I get an error "Error in do.call("rbind", dbGetQuery(con, queries))$value : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: If I use dbSendQuery as you suggest the error I get is: "Error in do.call("rbind", dbSendQuery(con, queries)) : 
  second argument must be a list"

Comment: Updated my response with an sapply.

Comment: That works! One more thing though that I forgot to add to my original question. Some searches won't be found in my database so I have several queries which will have no database entries. Is there a way to fill in "NA" for those entries?

Comment: That is what the coalesce(value,0) part of the query should be doing. Basically it is saying either do value, or if null do 0. You can replace the 0 with whatever you want. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: that works if there is an entry for that Chrom and Pos in the database. My problem is that many sites are not found in the database at all. I have 1255 entries that I'm searching, but only 974 have database entries.

Comment: Did some poking around, you can do this with a UNION ALL. Try the new example above. Value needs to be the same type as what you select from the original query. So change 0 in the SELECT 0 part of the union all portion of the query to be whatever you want the default to be.

Comment: Also if you just want null there, you can do a `...UNION ALL SELECT null LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [data.table package](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) for this kind of tasks as its syntax is inspired by SQL

```
require(data.table)
```

So an example database to match the values to a table

```
table <- data.table(chrom=rep(1:5, each=5), 
                    site=rep(100*1:5, times=5), 
                    Value=runif(5*5))
```

Now the SQL query can be translated into something like

```
# select from table, where chrom=Chr and site=Site, value
Chr <- 2
Site <- 200
table[chrom==Chr & site==Site, Value] # returns data.table
table[chrom==Chr & site==Site, ]$Value # returns numeric
```

Key (index) database for quick lookup (assuming unique chrom and site..)

```
setkey(table, chrom, site)
table[J(Chr, Site), ]$Value # very fast lookup due to indexed table
```

Your dataframe as data table with two columns 'Chr' and 'Site' both integer

```
df <- data.frame("Chr"=c(1,1,3,5,5), "Site"=c(100, 200, 400, 100, 300))
dt <- as.data.table(df) # adds data.table class to data.frame
setkey(dt, Chr, Site) # index for 'by' and for 'J' join
```

Match the values and append in new column (by reference, so no copying of table)

```
# loop over keys Chr and Site and find the match in the table
# select the Value column and create a new column that contains this
dt[, Value:=table[chrom==Chr & site==Site]$Value, by=list(Chr, Site)]
# faster:
dt[, Value:=table[J(Chr, Site)]$Value, by=list(Chr, Site)]
# fastest: in one table merge operation assuming the keys are in the same order
table[J(dt)]
```

kind greetings

Comment: This looks great. However I'm trying to access an already existing MySQL database with many tables I will have to access multiple times. I'm not sure how this will increase the efficiency...

Comment: i believe that if the SQL db is sorted by your indexes chrom and site the keying is not so painfull. Without keying you must use the double condition selection a==A&b==B which is slow. If its possible you could keep the tables in memory to not lose the indexing step.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) or [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html) package?

With [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html), you get MySQL access in R.

With [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html), you can issue SQL queries on R data structures.

Using either of those, you do not need to reword you SQL query to get the same results.

Let me also mention the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package, which lets you do very efficient selects and joins on your data frames after converting them to data tables using `as.data.table(your.data.frame)`. Another good thing about it is that a data.table object is a data.frame at the same time, so all your functions that work on the data frames work on these converted objects, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use **dplyr** package. There is even nice vignette about that - http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html.

One thing you need to know is:

> You can connect to MySQL and MariaDB (a recent fork of MySQL) through
>   src_mysql(), mediated by the RMySQL package. Like PostgreSQL, you'll
>   need to provide a dbname, username, password, host, and port.